# Display blog posts in a multisite network (Wordpress) across websites

Tags: wordpress, networking, posts, elementor, multisite

First of all: I don't know if I'm just too stupid for this, but I've already googled it and tried various solutions (codes inserted in the functions.php or even downloaded plugins) but my problem hasn't been solved. Maybe you know more.

My setup:

- Wordpress Multisite installation with two websites:
  --> One website is the "main site"
  --> The other website is the "blog site"
- The websites were created with Elementor.

Now I would like to display the posts from the "blog website" on the home page of the "main website" using the default Elementor layout for posts.

Isn't it possible that Wordpress simply accesses these posts? As far as I know, they are even in the same database?
The few plugins that are available have to be styled too much with CSS - that wouldn't be worth it.  Above all, the plugin I tested didn't even work (Network Posts Extended).

What I also don't want is that the posts are simply duplicated, because then I wouldn't need two websites. So ideally when you click on a post, you get redirected to the "blog website".

Hope you know what I mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone to know how I solved this problem:

- It didn't work with any of these plugins for multisite blogs etc.
- also didn't any code work

Instead I installed the plugin "WP RSS Aggregator" and bought their premium extension called "templates" so you can customize how the posts look like. In the plugin, you define the RSS Feed it should get the posts from (in my example the "blog site") and set it up like you need it.

That's all, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[netsposts post_type='post']` with Network Posts Extended plugin.
That worked for me.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your message. I tried it, activated the plugin on all sites, but it doesn't work, no matter what shortcodes I try, I don't see any posts. ;(

Comment: Can you "Network Activate" that plugin and let me know?

Comment: Yeah I tried to network activate it, but still doesn't show any posts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, they are not accessible in the way you described. Even trough they are saved in the same database they use a different table to store the posts each website (in a multi site) is prefixed by its index number. For example (using the default WordPress prefix) wp_1_posts and wp_2_posts.